# Receive/install application updates from code

Tags: android, google-play, manual

I would like to control android app updates (app is published on Google Play). In my situation, automatic updates are turned off in Play Store, and user needs to search for updates (and install if available) manually - by click on button, menu item or else. Is there a way to implement this? (e.g. send request to Google Play or something like that)
Thanks in advance.
Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Google support this, but since you know the application package, you can use a unoficial library to get information about your application (so the current version on the Play Store)

Here is the link to a library : http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

It seems to be a little old and I don't know if it's currently maintenaid

The best way is to implement a little WebService (or a simple page on a server) on your own and check against it

You can check it at the application startup and display a Dialog for instance

Comment: Seems like this library is not actually what I'm looking for. Thanks for the WebService idea, I'll try it.